# lookup() nodes inside a TabPane not working

Tags: java, javafx

this can sound wierd but when I do use the lookup() Method to find the nodes I want by ID, if the node is inside a TabPane, it simply won't fint it at all. I've googled it a lot, someone said that lookup() does not work for nodes with content inside, wich is the TabPane case. Is there a simple workaround? I didn't wanted to remove the Pane from my UI. Thanks.

code:

```
public class WindowDataFacade {

private Button btn_connect          = null;
private Button btn_disconnect       = null;
private Button btn_serv_opt         = null;
private TextField fld_username      = null;
private TextField sv_address        = null;
private PasswordField passwd_field  = null;
private TextField sv_port           = null;
private ProgressBar progress        = null;
private ProgressIndicator indicator = null;

public WindowDataFacade(Parent root) {

//Tried to use the lookup() method on the TabPane, but, no success at all.
    TabPane tpane =  (TabPane) root.getScene().lookup("#tab_pane");
    tpane.lookup("#fld_userame");

    btn_connect = (Button) root.getScene().lookup("#btn_connect");
    btn_disconnect = (Button) root.getScene().lookup("#btn_disconnect");
    fld_username = (TextField) tpane.getScene().lookup("#fld_userame");
    passwd_field = (PasswordField) root.getScene().lookup("#passwd_field");
    sv_port = (TextField) root.getScene().lookup("#sv_port");
    sv_address = (TextField) root.getScene().lookup("#sv_address");
    progress = (ProgressBar) root.getScene().lookup("#progress");
    indicator = (ProgressIndicator) root.getScene().lookup("#indicator");
}
```

The Main Class:

```
public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        private Stage mainStage;
        private MainScene scene;
        private FXController fxControl = null;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("run: " + Thread.currentThread());
            mainStage = new Stage();
            try {
//              root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxgui.fxml"));
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxgui.fxml"));
                Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
                fxControl = loader.getController();
                scene = new MainScene(root);
                scene.initialize(null, null);
                mainStage.setScene(scene);
                fxControl.setFacade(scene.getFacade());

                Button node = (Button) mainStage.getScene().lookup("#btn_disconnect");
                node.setDisable(true);

                mainStage.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    System.out.println("public void start: " + Thread.currentThread());

}
```

The Scene Class:

```
public class MainScene extends Scene implements Initializable {

Parent root = null;

@FXML
private Button btn_connect = new Button();
@FXML
private Button btn_disconnect = new Button();
@FXML
private Button btn_serv_opt = new Button();
@FXML
private TextField fld_username = new TextField();
@FXML
private TextField sv_address = new TextField();
@FXML
private PasswordField passwd_field = new PasswordField();
@FXML
private TextField sv_port = new TextField();
@FXML
private ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar();
@FXML
private ProgressIndicator indicator = new ProgressIndicator();

public MainScene(Parent root) {
    super(root);
    this.root = root;
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    //Setting and ID for each node.
    btn_connect.setId("btn_connect");
    btn_disconnect.setId("btn_disconnect");
    fld_username.setId("fld_username");
    passwd_field.setId("passwd_field");
    sv_address.setId("sv_address");
    sv_port.setId("sv_port");
    progress.setId("progress");
    indicator.setId("indicator");

}

public WindowDataFacade getFacade() {
    return new WindowDataFacade(root);
}

}
```

(The FXML isnt formatting correctly on this page for some reason, so I couldn't paste it here, but for sure the TabPane is there, with those nodes I cannot access)

Comment: Is this a controller class? And please edit the question to include the FXML. Just copy and paste it in, select it, and then press the "Code" button `{ }` in the edit pane.

Comment: No, this is not a controller class, I'll post some more code.

Comment: So why are some fields annotated `@FXML`?

Comment: I mixed the codes, so I tought It could be easier to understand, I'll undo this right now.

Comment: Does the annotations need to be inside the controller class? because they aren't. They are on the MainScene class.

Comment: Honestly, your code is so convoluted that I can't really tell what you're trying to do. But I don't think any of this is going to work. Your `MainScene` class instantiates a bunch of controls, but those are never made part of the scene graph, as far as I can tell. So they will never be retrieved by a lookup. On top of that, lookups only work once the scene graph has been rendered, so even if those controls were part of a scene, you are trying to look them up too early. Why don't you use the usual pattern where you reference the scene graph nodes in the controller?

Comment: And, yes, `@FXML` annotations outside of the controller class are meaningless. That annotation is just an instruction to the `FXMLLoader` to inject fields into the controller it uses.

Comment: Got it, hmm, no idea on how to do that pattern.

Comment: See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm). There are hundreds of other examples of using FXML with controllers online, just google...